# How can I make 2 spinboxes, each with different information, scroll together simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python and tkinter and was wondering how to link two spinboxes together so that when I scroll through one, the other automatically scrolls with it.

I managed to make this work like this:

```
    names1 = open('textfile_I_imported', 'r')
    names1_file = names.read()

    names2 = open('diff_texfile_I_imported', 'r')
    names2_file = names2.read()

    spinvalue = tk.StringVar()

    spinbox1=tk.Spinbox(self, textvariable=spinvalue, values=(textfile_I_imported))
    spinbox1.config(width='25')
    spinbox1.place(x=55, y=145)

    spinbox2=tk.Spinbox(self, textvariable=spinvalue, values=(diff_textfile_I_imported))
    spinbox2.config(width='45')
    spinbox2.place(x=225, y=145)
```

But this makes the same information show across the two spinboxes.

How can I make it so that scrolling through the spinbox1 makes spinbox2 scroll at the same time whilst showing *different* information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign functions to `Spinbox`es using `command=`.

Function can get selected value in one `Spinbox`, find its index on list of all values, get from second list value with the same index and use in second `Spinbox`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def sb1_changed(): # first spinbox
    selected = sb1_var.get()    
    idx = vals1.index(selected)
    print('selected:', selected)
    print('index:', idx)
    sb2_var.set(vals2[idx])

def sb2_changed(): # second spinbox
    selected = sb2_var.get()
    idx = vals2.index(selected)
    print('selected:', selected)
    print('index:', idx)
    sb1_var.set(vals1[idx])

# --- main ---

vals1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
vals2 = ['1', '2', '3']

root = tk.Tk()

sb1_var = tk.StringVar()
sb2_var = tk.StringVar()

sb1 = tk.Spinbox(root, textvariable=sb1_var, values=vals1, command=sb1_changed)
sb1.pack()

sb2 = tk.Spinbox(root, textvariable=sb2_var, values=vals2, command=sb2_changed)
sb2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Maybe using arguments you could use only one function and execute `changed(sb1, sb2)` and `changed(sb2, sb1)`

Comment: Thank you - this was very useful.